# Possible Issues why Timer().schedule() in Kotlin didn't work for my project

Tags: kotlin, scheduler

I have used the Timer().schedule in a kotlin project to schedule a task to be executed once a day.

**Function prototype -** public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)

**My Code:**

```
val calender = Calendar.getInstance()
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5)
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
    val executionTime = calender.time

    Timer().schedule(
        timerTask {
            runBlocking {
                launch {
                    try {
                        log.info("Scheduler Executed!")
                    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                        log.error(
                            "Found Exception: $exception"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        },executionTime, TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24)
 )
```

**Issue Description:** My server is based on UTC, I set the 'firstTime' as 5:30, which corresponds to 11:00 AM in IST. The deployment time was nearly 22:00 IST, which is greater than the 'firstTime', so the task should get executed at that time, and from the next day it should be running at 22:00 IST daily. But the task never got executed.

The task should have got executed during the deployment and daily at 22:00 IST hence there wasn't any error, but it wasn't. I later replaced the Timer.schedule() with Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() and it's working properly. But I am not able to find out why the previous one didn't work. Any views from your side would be helpful. Thank You!